# How to fix SyntaxError: "Unexpected token '?' at wrapSafe..." on Google App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I would like to publish my app on Google App Engine, but the deployment process is unsuccessful. In the end, I receive an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-01-19T17:11:53.140Z7387.zq.2: An internal error occurred while creating your deployment. Please try again later or contact Google Support.
```

I investigated logs and I found this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32) 
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@15.0.2 serve:ssr: `node dist/my-app/server/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@15.0.2 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging 
output above.
```

but to be honest I am unable to evaluate, where this error comes from. Locally the app works without any issues. Could anybody give me some advice? Thank You.

Tech stack:

```
Angular 15 SSR
Node: 18.10.0
Typescript: 4.8.4
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "15.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start:dev": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run my-app:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/my-app/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration production && ng run my-app:server",
    "prerender": "ng run my-app:prerender",
    "prepare": "npm run build:ssr",
    "start": "npm run serve:ssr"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.0.0",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^15.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

The app.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
instance_class: F4
resources:
  memory_gb: 4
automatic_scaling:
  max_concurrent_requests: 55
```

The tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: finally, I decided to say goodbye to Google App Engine, Dockerize my app, and run the container in Google Cloud Run.